# Zusammen oder getrennt? Gibt es eine Regel?

Tags: vocabulary, spelling

Es gibt viele Wörter im Deutschen, deren exakte Schreibweise sich meiner Kenntnis schon immer entzogen haben. Das größte Problem ist dabei die Frage: zusammen oder getrennt?

Ich nenne mal ein paar Beispiele:

- des weiteren
- deswegen
- zuzugeben
- insofern

Gibt es eine allgemein gültige Regel (und natürlich deren Ausnahmen), mit der man feststellen (*fest stellen?*) kann, ob ein solches Wort zusammen oder getrennt geschrieben wird?

Comment: des Weiteren übrigens mit großem W :)

Comment: Okay, das kommt noch dazu - aber ist desweiteren auch akzeptabel? Sehe ich zumindest sehr oft.

Comment: Das hat sich durch die unsägliche Rechtschreibreform *mehrmals* geändert, und es sind oft mehrere Schreibweisen akzeptiert. Ich mache das nur noch nach Gefühl und schreibe grundsätzlich zusammen (z.B. „desweiteren“) und tendenziell nach der alten Rechtschreibung, die ich (überwiegend) in der Schule gelernt habe, solange es die Lesbarkeit nicht beeinträchtigt. Da die deutsche Rechtschreibung im Gegensatz zur französischen eh nur deskriptiv ist, und Zusammenschreibungsregeln notorisch inkonsistent, ist das allgemein toleriert.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: "des Weiteren" wurde nach alter wie neuer Rechtschreibung getrennt geschrieben. Ich gebe dir recht; meist kann man sich nach seinem Gefühl richten - aber allgemein toleriert ist alte bzw. falsche Rechtschreibung je nach Umgebung nicht unbedingt. Daher würde ich mich eher nach der Duden-Empfehlung (gelb hinterlegt im papiernen Duden) richten, die bei mehreren erlaubten auch mitunter die alte Rechtschreibung bevorzugt (z.B. aufwendig). Die zweite Rechtschreibreform (also erster Teil der aktuellen, 2001?) war unglücklich, der zweite Teil hingegen (2006) gefällt mir ganz gut.

Comment: @OregonGhost ‚"des Weiteren" wurde nach alter wie neuer Rechtschreibung getrennt geschrieben‘ – ist mir bekannt, aber wie gesagt habe ich komplett aufgehört, mich danach zu richten, da die offiziellen Regeln komplett losgelöst vom tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch und nur noch unsinnig sind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In aller Regel kann man die Getrennt- oder Zusammenschreibung von Wörtern an der Semantik erkennen. Seit der letzten Rechtschreibreform sind die Regeln auch *verhältnismäßig* eindeutig, wenn auch sehr kompliziert. Ich versuche hier mal, sie *zusammenzufassen*.

### Verben

Wenn ein Verb verwendet werden soll, muss nur darauf geachtet werden, dass es nach einer möglichen Trennung noch ein Verb ist:

> Ich werde wohl **sitzenbleiben**. (Vgl. Ich **werde wohl sitzen** bleiben.)
>
> Ich werde einfach alles **zusammenschreiben**. (Vgl. Ich werde einfach **alles zusammen** schreiben.)

#### Zusammengeschrieben werden

- Adverb + Verb, wo der Hauptton auf dem Adverb liegt

  > beisammenbleiben
- Verbindungen aus Verb + Verb, wo der zweite Teil *bleiben* oder *lassen* ist

  > bleibenlassen
- Substantiv + Verb, um eine Zusammensetzung zu bilden

  > Danksagung

#### Getrennt geschrieben werden

- Adverb + Verb, wenn der Hauptton auf dem Verb liegt

  > zusammen lernen
  >
  > gemeinsam gehen
- Andere Verbindungen aus Verb + Verb

  > schwimmen gehen

#### Beide Formen sind erlaubt, wenn

- in Zusammenschlüssen aus Adjektiv und Verb das Adjektiv das Ergebnis des Verbes ausdrückt

  > warm halten / warmhalten
  >
  > fest schrauben / festschrauben

### Adjektive

Bei Verbindungen mit Adjektiven wird *nur* dann zusammengeschrieben, wenn sie als Einheit wahrgenommen werden:

> Das Experiment war Aufsehen erregend. (Hatte Aufsehen erregt – hätte auch Ekel erregen können.)
>
> Die Pflanzen sind selbstleuchtend. (Leuchteten nicht selbst, sondern hatten die Eigenschaft der Photolumineszenz.)

#### Beide Formen sind erlaubt, wenn

- in Zusammenschlüssen aus Adjektiv und Adjektiv das erste Adjektiv das zweite *verringert*:

  > schwer erziehbar / schwererziehbar
- man ein Partizip als Adjektiv gebraucht

  > rechts drehend / rechtsdrehend

Substantive, die aus anderen Sprachen entlehnt sind, dürfen im Übrigen auch zusammengeschrieben werden:

> Fastfood
>
> Standingovations

Comment: Ich finde die Beispiele etwas unglücklich, aber das ist mehr gefühlt als gewusst: Zusammenschreiben kann etwas anderes als zusammen (gemeinsam) schreiben bedeuten. Sitzenbleiben (in der Schule nicht versetzt werden) ist etwas anderes als sitzen bleiben (sich nicht vom Stuhl erheben). Die Faustregel, dass übertragene Bedeutungen zusammengeschrieben (oder zusammen geschrieben? *Erlaubt* ist sicherlich beides) werden, wörtliche jedoch getrennt, finde ich gut. Das zusammengeschriebene Wort ist somit keine andere Schreibweise, sondern ein neues Wort mit eigenem Kontext und eigener Bedeutung.

Comment: Genau, darauf wollte ich hinaus. Gut, dass es angekommen ist. :-) Bei den Beispielen brauche ich aber in der Tat Hilfe. Vielleicht sollte diese Antwort ein Community-Wiki sein?

Comment: *Aufsehen erregend* ist ein unglückliches Beispiel: Die Form ist zwar erlaubt, der Duden empfiehlt jedoch *aufsehenerregend*. Interessant ist andererseits die Bedeutung: *einiges Aufsehen erregend*, was zwangsweise auseinander geschrieben werden muss :)

Answer (score 7):

Eine echte, *allgemeingültige* Regel ist mir nicht bekannt. Während man bei Verben oder Adjektiven noch über die Frage, wie eng die Wortbestandteile *zusammengehören*, zu einer Antwort kommen kann und Substantive pauschal zusammenschreibt, dürfte man bei den erwähnten Beispielen eher ein Wörterbuch bemühen müssen. Diese Beispiele werden aber *im Allgemeinen* zusammengeschrieben, bis auf einige Ausnahmen, wie *des Weiteren*.

Ansonsten gilt: Wenn die Wortbestandteile in ihrer übertragenen Bedeutung verwendet werden oder eine enge Sinneinheit bilden, werden sie zusammengeschrieben. Deshalb wird *zusammenschreiben* zusammengeschrieben, ebenso wie dein Beispiel *feststellen*. Dabei *stellt* man durchaus *fest*, dass man viele Verben *auseinanderbrechen* kann, aber nicht alle.

Durch Getrenntschreibung kann man auch eine Bedeutung ändern bzw. betonen. Auch hier ist die Frage, ob die übertragene Bedeutung verwendet wird (Beispiel nicht von mir):

> die Arbeit ist liegengeblieben (aber: Sie ist heute Morgen im Bett liegen geblieben.)

Am besten verlässt du dich auf dein Gefühl, wenn du nicht *nachschlagen* kannst. Im Zweifel werden viele Dinge dann doch zusammengeschrieben und lesen sich auch seltsam *fremdartig*, wenn sie getrennt werden.

Comment: Das Beispiel ist wirklich krass, wo hast du es her? Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es Stoff für einen ganzer Artikel bietet.